# Polymorphic methods inside constructor

Tags: polymorphism

''Why in this code testSon class void display() method is called instead of               testFather class void display()

```
   class testFather  
     {  

        void display()  
        {  
                System.out.println("This is testFather class");   
        }  
        testFather()  //testFather constructor
        {  
            display();  
        }  

    }  

    class testSon extends testFather  
    {  

        void display()  
        {  

            System.out.println("This is testSon class ");  
        }  

        testSon()   //testSon class Constructor 
        {  
            int i=100;  
            System.out.println("This is cons of testSon class");  
        }  
    }  


    public class testConstructor   
    {  
       public static void main(String[] args)  
       {  
           testSon ts = new testSon();  
       }  
    }
```

''Output :  This is testSon class    /* why not This is testFather class*/
          This is cons of testSon class

Answer (score 0):

You created a testson object.  Therefor its constructor gets called. If you want to call the parents also  use super()  in constructor.  If this is java as I presume.

Edit: On another note it does not seems that you are calling the display() function in your testSon constructor, rather you are calling system.out.println within it.

your code:

```
 testSon()   //testSon class Constructor 
        {  
            int i=100;  
            System.out.println("This is cons of testSon class");  
        }
```